# What is the minimum size for a hard drive to use ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04

What is the minimum size to install and use ubuntu comfortably?

I am looking in to something like elementary OS on a 32gb ssd. is that possible or would i not have enough space for everything?

Comment: This entirely depends on what else you plan to install. For example, if you install games, then you need more space than someone who doesn't install games.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements Beyond that how many applications are you planning to install and what are your data requirements ?

Comment: Ubuntu works just fine in my 8GB EC2 instance. There is no GUI though...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Comment: @karel I would argue this is different because OP wants to install a *SPECIFIC* Ubuntu version and wants to know if his specs would perform.

Comment: To be specific, any currently supported version of Ubuntu can be installed on 10GB disk space and Ubuntu Server requires a minimum of only 1.4GB disk space, but it will be cramped if it is not given more disk space. A 32GB SSD will be large enough for some, and a 64GB SSD will be fine for most people.

Answer (score 1):

Shortly, "**yes**", however you may run into slow file transferring and other problems due to a small SSD, especially if you intend to be using any large programs, such as games. The bare-minimum required specs that can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) are as follows:

1. 700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
2. 512 MiB RAM (system memory)
3. 5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
4. A display capable of 1024x768 resolution
5. Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
6. Internet access is helpful

Comment: i only intend to do some light progamming, i just want the system to start fast and be snappy

Comment: Not sure if it would be  as "fast and snappy" as for example my 3 TB drive ***;)*** but it'll get the job done!

Comment: 32GB should be fast and snappy if you're not a pack rat. The slowest, oldest SSD is noticeably faster than any HDD.

Comment: @karel Depends again on what "light programming" means, hence [on hold]